# Why iewebgl + threejs flips vertically my uvmapped texture?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, three.js, webgl, texture-mapping

I'm currently developing a 3D viewer for game pads.
The goal is to personalize the pad with different colours and materials.

First of all, I realised a simple ".bin .js " loader, with sample materials.
I used Threejs r62 to make a prototype of the visualizer.
Cool, it works.
But for IE I wanted to use IEWEBGL to make it more reachable.
Cool, it works...

but ...

**My problem here  :**

The problem is that when I use the plugin, Both I.E and firefox (and chrome also) output the same strange thing :
The object model has a **wrong  UV texture placement** compared to the initial version of the code without IEWEBGL's moifications.

**My question here  :**
Do somebody know when and why the image is vertically flipped ?

See here the 3d viewer : [without the use of IEWEBGL helper](http://tinyurl.com/np6vw96)

And now : 
[with IE WEBGL](http://tinyurl.com/opzpqgu)

The code is available below after the post.
Tell me if my request is not precise enough or if I should reformulate something.
Thanx for all in advance, I hope some threejs or iewebgl Guru will have some "cool tips".

Ju

---

*NOTES :*

Threejs nature sample code of my page :

```
        <script>

// MAIN

// standard global variables
var container, scene, camera, renderer, controls, stats;
//var keyboard = new THREEx.KeyboardState();
var clock = new THREE.Clock();

// Vars


init();
animate();

// FUNCTIONS        
function init() 
{
    // SCENE
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // CAMERA
    //~ var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth, SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
    //~ var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth, SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerWidth;

            var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
            var SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;         
            var scale = 100;    

    var VIEW_ANGLE = 65, ASPECT = SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, NEAR = 0.1, FAR = 20000;
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR);
    scene.add(camera);
    camera.position.set(0,0,4);
    //~ camera.lookAt(scene.position);

    // RENDERER
    if ( Detector.webgl )
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
    else
    renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer(); 

    // RENDERER OTHER SETUP

        renderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
        // CAST SHADOWS             
        //~ renderer.shadowMapEnabled   = true;
        //~ renderer.sortObjects = false;
        //~ renderer.shadowCameraNear = 2;
        //~ renderer.shadowCameraFar = 1500;
        //~ renderer.shadowCameraFov = 50;
        //~ renderer.physicallyBasedShading = true;
        //~ renderer.setClearColorHex( 0x000000, 0 );

        container = document.createElement( 'div' );
        document.body.appendChild( container );
        container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );


    // EVENTS
    //~ THREEx.WindowResize(renderer, camera);
    //~ THREEx.FullScreen.bindKey({ charCode : 'm'.charCodeAt(0) });

    // CONTROLS
    controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera );
    //~ controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );

    // LIGHT

                // add spot lighting
                var spot = new THREE.SpotLight( 0xffffff, 1 );

                spot.position.set( 5,5, 5 );
                spot.lookAt( scene.position );
                spot.castShadow = true;
                spot.shadowCameraVisible = true;
                spot.shadowMapBias = 1;
                spot.shadowMapWidth = 1024;
                spot.shadowMapHeight    = 1024;
                spot.shadowMapSoft      = true; 
                spot.shadowMapDarkness = 1;
                scene.add( spot );

                // create a point light // set its position // add to the scene

                var pointLightOne = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff );
                pointLightOne.position.set( -5,-5, -5 );
                scene.add(pointLightOne);

                var pointLightTwo = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff );
                pointLightTwo.position.set( 5,5, 5 );
                scene.add(pointLightTwo);


                //~ // add ambient lighting
                var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x0b0b0b);
                scene.add(ambientLight);



    ////////////
    // CUSTOM //
    ////////////

    // axes
    //~ var axes = new THREE.AxisHelper(100);
    //~ scene.add( axes );



                // ENVAMP
                var r = "../data/envmap/";
                var urls = [ r + "px.jpg", r + "nx.jpg",
                             r + "py.jpg", r + "ny.jpg",
                             r + "pz.jpg", r + "nz.jpg" ];
                var textureCube = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTextureCube( urls );


                // 3D LOADER                
                var loader = new THREE.BinaryLoader();  

                // OBJECT Dragon
                loader.load( "../data/3d//33.js", function( geometry ) { createScene( geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xf5ffba,shading: THREE.SmoothShading,envMap: textureCube, combine: THREE.MixOperation, reflectivity: 0.10,map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "../data/2d/84.jpg" )}) ) } );  

                // OBJECT Classique
                loader.load( "../data/3d//34.js", function( geometry ) { createScene( geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xfcf9fc,shading: THREE.SmoothShading,map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "../data/2d/55.jpg" )}) ) } );   

                // OBJECT Classique
                loader.load( "../data/3d//40.js", function( geometry ) { createScene( geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x242224,shading: THREE.SmoothShading,envMap: textureCube, combine: THREE.MultiplyOperation, reflectivity: 0.1}) ) } );   

                // OBJECT Noir Classique
                loader.load( "../data/3d//35.js", function( geometry ) { createScene( geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x242224,shading: THREE.SmoothShading,envMap: textureCube, combine: THREE.MultiplyOperation, reflectivity: 0.1}) ) } );   

                // OBJECT Noir
                loader.load( "../data/3d//36.js", function( geometry ) { createScene( geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x242224,shading: THREE.SmoothShading,envMap: textureCube, combine: THREE.MultiplyOperation, reflectivity: 0.1}) ) } );   

                // OBJECT Noir
                loader.load( "../data/3d//37.js", function( geometry ) { createScene( geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x242224,shading: THREE.SmoothShading,envMap: textureCube, combine: THREE.MultiplyOperation, reflectivity: 0.1}) ) } );   

                // OBJECT Noires
                loader.load( "../data/3d//39.js", function( geometry ) { createScene( geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x242224,shading: THREE.SmoothShading,envMap: textureCube, combine: THREE.MultiplyOperation, reflectivity: 0.1}) ) } );   

                // OBJECT Noires
                loader.load( "../data/3d//38.js", function( geometry ) { createScene( geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x242224,shading: THREE.SmoothShading,envMap: textureCube, combine: THREE.MultiplyOperation, reflectivity: 0.1}) ) } );   

                // OBJECT Noir
                loader.load( "../data/3d//41.js", function( geometry ) { createScene( geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x242224,shading: THREE.SmoothShading,envMap: textureCube, combine: THREE.MultiplyOperation, reflectivity: 0.1}) ) } );   

                // OBJECT XBPLUG
                loader.load( "../data/3d//42.js", function( geometry ) { createScene( geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xffffff,shading: THREE.SmoothShading,envMap: textureCube, combine: THREE.MultiplyOperation, reflectivity: 0.9}) ) } );   


                var texture, material, ground;

                texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "../data/2d/images/shadow.png" );
                //~ texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;  // This doesnt seem to work;
                material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ map : texture });
                ground = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(6, 6), material);
                ground.doubleSided = true;
                //~ ground.rotation.set(-1.5707963267949,0,0);
                ground.rotation.set(-1.5707963267949,0,0);
                ground.position.set(0,-2,0);
                //~ ground.scale.set( 5, 5, 5);
                ground.overdraw = true;
                ground.receiveShadow = true;
                ground.rotation.z = 2;  // Not sure what this number represents.
                scene.add(ground);


}

function createScene( geometry, materials ) {
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, materials );

    // POSITION                         
    mesh.position.set(0,0.5,0);
    mesh.scale.set( 1, 1, 1 );

    scene.add( mesh );
}


function animate() 
{
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    render();       
    update();
}

function update()
{
    /*if ( keyboard.pressed("z") ) 
    { 
        // do something
    }*/

    controls.update();
    stats.update();

camera.position.x = 15 * Math.cos( theta );
camera.position.y = 10;
camera.position.z = 15 * Math.sin( theta );

}

function render() 
{
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

        </script>
```

And this is the code with little change for IEWEBGL

```
<script>


        // stub for "console" object, because IE does not have it, when page is not under debugger.
        var console = console || {
            'warn': function (msg) { },
            'log': function (msg) { },
            'error': function (msg) { }
        };

        var container, stats;

        var camera, controls, scene, renderer;


        var clock;

        function start() {
            require(["../core/vues/plugin/threejs62_ie/js/Three.js"], function () {
                init();
                animate();
            });
        }

        function init() {


            container = document.getElementById('container');
            //~ clock = new THREE.Clock();

            // RENDERER
            var externalCanvas = document.getElementById('renderCanvas');


            if ( Detector.webgl ) {
                //~ renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();
                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ 'canvas': externalCanvas });
            }
            else {
                Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();
                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ 'canvas': externalCanvas });

                //~ renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer({ 'canvas': externalCanvas }); 
                if ($.browser.msie) {
                    //~ alert('IE');    
                    }

            }


            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

// CAMERA


            var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
            var SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;         
            var scale = 100;    


            var VIEW_ANGLE = 65, ASPECT = SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, NEAR = 0.1, FAR = 20000;

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR );
            scene.add( camera );

            camera.position.set( 0, 0, 5);

        // CONTROLS
        controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera );


////////////
// CUSTOM //
////////////


// LIGHT

            // add spot lighting
            var spot = new THREE.SpotLight( 0xffffff, 1 );

            spot.position.set( 5,5, 5 );
            spot.lookAt( scene.position );
            spot.castShadow = true;
            spot.shadowCameraVisible = true;
            spot.shadowMapBias = 1;
            spot.shadowMapWidth = 1024;
            spot.shadowMapHeight    = 1024;
            spot.shadowMapSoft      = true; 
            spot.shadowMapDarkness = 1;
            scene.add( spot );

            // create a point light // set its position // add to the scene

            var pointLightOne = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff );
            pointLightOne.position.set( -5,-5, -5 );
            scene.add(pointLightOne);

            var pointLightTwo = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff );
            pointLightTwo.position.set( 5,5, 5 );
            scene.add(pointLightTwo);


            //~ // add ambient lighting
            var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x0b0b0b);
            scene.add(ambientLight);



            // axes
            var axes = new THREE.AxisHelper(100);
            scene.add( axes );

            // ENVAMP
            var r = "../data/envmap/";
            var urls = [ r + "px.jpg", r + "nx.jpg",
                         r + "py.jpg", r + "ny.jpg",
                         r + "pz.jpg", r + "nz.jpg" ];
            var textureCube = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTextureCube( urls );


            // 3D LOADER                
            var loader = new THREE.BinaryLoader();  

            // OBJECT Dragon
            loader.load( "../data/3d//33.js", function( geometry ) { createScene( geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xf5ffba,shading: THREE.SmoothShading,envMap: textureCube, combine: THREE.MixOperation, reflectivity: 0.10,map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "../data/2d/84.jpg" )}) ) } );  

            // OBJECT Classique
            loader.load( "../data/3d//34.js", function( geometry ) { createScene( geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xfcf9fc,shading: THREE.SmoothShading,map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "../data/2d/55.jpg" )}) ) } );   

            // OBJECT Classique
            loader.load( "../data/3d//40.js", function( geometry ) { createScene( geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x242224,shading: THREE.SmoothShading,envMap: textureCube, combine: THREE.MultiplyOperation, reflectivity: 0.1}) ) } );   

            // OBJECT Noir Classique
            loader.load( "../data/3d//35.js", function( geometry ) { createScene( geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x242224,shading: THREE.SmoothShading,envMap: textureCube, combine: THREE.MultiplyOperation, reflectivity: 0.1}) ) } );   

            // OBJECT Noir
            loader.load( "../data/3d//36.js", function( geometry ) { createScene( geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x242224,shading: THREE.SmoothShading,envMap: textureCube, combine: THREE.MultiplyOperation, reflectivity: 0.1}) ) } );   

            // OBJECT Noir
            loader.load( "../data/3d//37.js", function( geometry ) { createScene( geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x242224,shading: THREE.SmoothShading,envMap: textureCube, combine: THREE.MultiplyOperation, reflectivity: 0.1}) ) } );   

            // OBJECT Noires
            loader.load( "../data/3d//39.js", function( geometry ) { createScene( geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x242224,shading: THREE.SmoothShading,envMap: textureCube, combine: THREE.MultiplyOperation, reflectivity: 0.1}) ) } );   

            // OBJECT Noires
            loader.load( "../data/3d//38.js", function( geometry ) { createScene( geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x242224,shading: THREE.SmoothShading,envMap: textureCube, combine: THREE.MultiplyOperation, reflectivity: 0.1}) ) } );   

            // OBJECT Noir
            loader.load( "../data/3d//41.js", function( geometry ) { createScene( geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x242224,shading: THREE.SmoothShading,envMap: textureCube, combine: THREE.MultiplyOperation, reflectivity: 0.1}) ) } );   

            // OBJECT XBPLUG
            loader.load( "../data/3d//42.js", function( geometry ) { createScene( geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xffffff,shading: THREE.SmoothShading,envMap: textureCube, combine: THREE.MultiplyOperation, reflectivity: 0.9}) ) } );   



            stats = new Stats();
            stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
            stats.domElement.style.top = '10px';
            container.appendChild( stats.domElement );

        }

        //

        function createScene( geometry, materials ) {
            var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, materials );

            // POSITION                         
            mesh.position.set(0,0.5,0);
            mesh.scale.set( 1, 1, 1 );

            scene.add( mesh );
        }


        function animate() 
        {
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            render();       
            update();
        }

        function update()
        {
            /*if ( keyboard.pressed("z") ) 
            { 
                // do something
            }*/

            controls.update();
            stats.update();
        }

        function render() 
        {

            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: could you try to focus more on your question. Try to ask a clear and well define question. Your context is great btw.

Comment: In fact I know how to fix my problem (*) but don't  know why it appears.
(* I just have to pre process the Image flip with GD for example in my script )

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED : Ok so first of all thanx for comments.
Temporarily, I made an imagemagick script to reverse on the fly the image.

And to complete, since IE11 was released, there is no need to use IEWEBGL anymore (actually in this way, it may be usefull for other things). 
IE11 comes with a native webgl context.